# c# - Load serval TreeView UserControls failed- Stack Overflow

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, treeview

### Background

- I want to load different treeview usercontrol through select RadioButtonList1.When i fist time load the aspx file ,and load ascx in Page_Load Event in the page, it is successfully display usercontrol and data in the master page.
- However , i can only load TreeView usercontrol only once , when i chose `RadioButtonList1` ,then execute `this.Placeholder1.Controls.Add(uc)` ,its failed.The programming can only display the usercontrol but it cannot load data.

### Attempt

- When i debug this Programming ,i find selected RadioButtonList1 cannot trigger any other event except Page_Load event in `TreeViewUserControl.ascx`. And when i click the node event,it show me some error , `Failed to find callback targets"ctl10$LinksTreeView" or Unrealized ICallbackEventHandler.`
- Someone tell me i need to set ID for usercontrol ,just like `uc.ID = "uc"`,it did change . When i click the BaseNode :

  - it can trigger `PopulateNode` event , and can only execute `PopulateCategories` method , but not `PopulateProducts`.
  - Just like before data load failed , but there is no hint `Failed to find callback targets"ctl10$LinksTreeView"......`.
- It took me several days to find the answer, but it never worked out.I want to get some help, thank you. This is my first time to ask questions ,forgive me for my poor English.

### Program code

- masterPage.aspx :

  ```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      AddTreeViewUserControlInPage();
  }

  protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex == 0)
      {
          ViewState["tree"] = "first";
          AddTreeViewUserControlInPage();
      }
      if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex == 1)
      {
          ViewState["tree"] = "second";
          AddTreeViewUserControlInPage();
      }
  }

  public void AddTreeViewUserControlInPage()
  {
      this.Placeholder1.Controls.Clear();
      string path = string.Empty;
      if (ViewState["tree"] == null)
      {
          path = "~/treeviewtest.ascx";
      }
      else
      {
          switch (ViewState["tree"].ToString())
          {
              case "first":
                  path = "~/treeviewtest.ascx";
                  break;
              case "second":
                  path = "~/TreeViewUserControl2.ascx";
                  break;
          }
      }
      Page p = new Page();
      Control uc = p1.LoadControl(path);
      //uc.ID = "uc";
      this.Placeholder1.Controls.Add(uc);
  }
  ```
- TreeViewUserControl.ascx

just like this one:[TreeView.TreeNodePopulate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.treenodepopulate.aspx)

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    public void PopulateNode(Object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Node.Depth)
        {
            case 0:
                PopulateCategories(e.Node);
                break;
            case 1:
                PopulateProducts(e.Node);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    public void PopulateCategories(TreeNode node)
    {
        //Omitted
    }
    public void PopulateProducts(TreeNode node)
    {
        //Omitted
    }
    DataSet RunQuery(String QueryString)
    {
        //Omitted
    }
```

- TreeViewUserControl.ascx

  ```
  <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="TreeViewUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="TreeViewUserControl" %>
  <asp:TreeView id="TreeView" Font-Names= "Arial" ForeColor="Black" EnableClientScript="true" PopulateNodesFromClient="true" OnTreeNodePopulate="PopulateNode"
  runat="server" ShowCheckBoxes="All"  ShowLines="True">
  <HoverNodeStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="False" />
  <Nodes>
      <asp:TreeNode Text="BaseNode" 
      SelectAction="Expand"  
      PopulateOnDemand="true"/>
  </Nodes>
  </asp:TreeView>
  <asp:Label id="Message" runat="server"/>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem，the way is to change `PopulateNodesFromClient="true"` into `PopulateNodesFromClient="false"`

Comment: But when i want to realise the ajax way to load usercontrol, then i put this `placeholder` into `<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">`， while the problem just like before.